# How can I stop my chrome extension injected button style from overriding?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension, stylesheet

I am currently working on a chrome extension, which injects few buttons on some sites, but I facing this problem that the button element styles are being overridden by that site’s css. What should I do to prevent that?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK to isolate your styles there are 2 most used options:

- using Shadow DOM
- put your elements and styles into an iframe

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to style the button using !important; in a way to style override the current websites style?

Comment: If I do so, that particular property remains intact, but other properties get applied which I have no use of. Like I specified my button width & height property followed by !important. But there are other properties being applied to my button that I don't want.